# npm package global install is not showing up in node_modules, but instead in nodist/bin

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

I'm tyring to install expo-cli using

`npm install -g expo-cli`

This completes with no errors, but I cannot access `expo` as a command in the console, even after relaunching. It just gives me the old path error (not recognized as internal or external command). When I look in user/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules`, the package is not there.

If I run `npm list -g` it gives me this output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin
`-- expo-cli@5.4.12
```

I've tried adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin` to my path in environment variables but no luck there either.

Comment: are you using command prompt or power shell? If you're using power shell, try `expo.cmd` instead of just `expo`

Comment: Just regular command prompt.